# Modifying an IEnumerator after declaration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerable

I have been working with Unity C#. I do not really understand IEnumerators, but suppose I have the following:

```
IEnumerator some_function(int a) { ... }

IEnumerator f = some_function(0);
```

Is there a way to change the parameter value of an existing `f` so that it is equivalent to having declared, for instance:

```
IEnumerator f = some_function(5);
```

Comment: You have already define the type of the varaible `f`. SO just remove `IEnumerator` from the second assignment. `f = some_function(5);`

Comment: Can you show the code inside some_function  method? I say it is possible but it really depends on the algorithm.

Comment: Your question title says your function returns `IEnumerable`. Your question body shows it returns `IEnumerator`. They aren't the same thing. I can understand that it is just a typo, but since there's no way of telling which is the typo: your functions should almost certainly not be returning `IEnumerator`. `IEnumerable` (out of the two) is the interface that can be used with `foreach`, with the many extension methods in `System.Linq.Enumerable`, and with most other methods. `IEnumerator` is mostly used behind the scenes.

Comment: I have fixed the title. See the Unity documentation on Coroutines:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html
The examples given return IEnumerator. The details of how the StartCoroutine function work in Unity may be something I need to understand further to properly pose this question.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that reference. It's a not very common (perhaps more common in Unity) but clever use of `IEnumerator`. :) You're right that in your case, you need `IEnumerator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is **No**.

You could call your method again obviously. Or you could package your behavior in a new class or method. But the `IEnumerable<>` or the used enumerator have no connection to the producer that would allow this.

Answer (score 2):

If you've not yet started enumerating over the results of your function, there's no problem at all with simply calling your function again:

```
IEnumerable f = some_function(0);
f = some_function(5);
```

If you *have* started enumerating over the results of your function already, and you want the existing invocation to continue with the new value, then consider a helper class:

```
class SomeFunctionData {
  public int a;
}

IEnumerable some_function(SomeFunctionData data);
```

and then

```
var data = new SomeFunctionData { a = 0 };
IEnumerable f = some_function(data);
...
data.a = 5;
```

If `some_function` continues looking at the existing `SomeFunctionData` instance, from then on, it will see the new value for `a`. Note that under most circumstances, this leads to a hard-to-understand program logic, so check if you really need this before implementing it, but there are some cases where it's useful.